# 66k lines to analyze in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I huge amount of data to analyze!
I have a table **"Resolved Met"** and on column G with some text that contains a server name 
and table **"Server List"** with 66k name of servers

I have to analyze if the text contains the server name on table **"Server List"** and if yes to write the server name in front of the text ( in another cell)

What I did was to go to first line of table **"Server List"** and look for it on column where the text is with a loop

It took more than 6 hours to analyze everything once the I have 66k serves name and 130k lines of text.
Here is my code. Do you have some better idea to make it faster?

```
Sub ()

i = 1
Sheets("Server List").Select
Range("A1").Select

servername = ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Value

Do Until IsEmpty(servername)

    Sheets("Resolved Met").Select

    With Worksheets("Resolved Met").Range("G:G")
        Set server = .find(What:=servername, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not server Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = server.Address
            Range(firstAddress).Select
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13) = servername
            Do
                Set server = .FindNext(server)
                If server Is Nothing Then
                    GoTo DoneFinding2
                End If
                SecondAdress = server.Address
                Range(SecondAdress).Select
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 13) = servername

            Loop While SecondAdress <> firstAddress
        End If
        DoneFinding2:
    End With


    Sheets("Server List").Select
    i = i + 1
    servername = ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Value

Loop
```

Comment: You should [avoid Activate and Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: The `.Find` call is certainly not helping performance much either. I'd consider using a `Dictionary` for a lookup instead.

Comment: Use a database (MS Access, SQLite for file level DBMS) or data set type program (SAS, Stata, SPSS) or open-source tool (Python pandas, R, Julia). These can hold large amount of data and search without looping

Comment: Would help a lot to show some examples of the data you're working with.  Also - do you need to find all matches, or just the first/last?  You code overwrites previous matches as each next match is found...

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad -  I will do that

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Guindon - Sorry, I just started to develop my skill with vba.

Comment: @Parfait - I Am learning Python, next ones will be unde this language

Comment: @TimWilliams Williams - See Link Bellow. It is an excel with what need to be done. Tks!

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fwTMra9DsqHm0jgXa34j2U3201Zfi5lT

Comment: In the longer text , is the server name always surrounded by spaces ?  You can use `Like` or `Instr` to check if some text is contained in some other text, but I'm guessing you'd want to be able to distinguish "server3" from "server33" for example.

Comment: @TimWilliams Some time they are surrounded by spaces and sometimes no. 
See a real comment example and real server names

comment - ITM Agent Offline:nzapie60
Server names - nzapie6 and nzapie60 (same example you gave me)

I did considered it till now. But server33 will not find server3 so if I sort them Server3 will find server33 and it is wrong, but it will be corrected at the time to find of server33

Answer (score 2):

You could utilize a `Dictionary` for this and achieve much better performance

```
Sub t()

    Dim dict As Object

    Dim i As Long
    Dim endrow As Long

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Sheets("Server List")
        endrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To endrow
            If .Range("A" & i) <> "" Then
                dict.Add CStr(.Range("A" & i)), .Range("A" & i)
            End If
        Next

    End With

    With Sheets("Resolved Met")
        endrow = .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To endrow
            If dict.Exists(CStr(.Range("G" & i))) Then
                .Range("G" & i).Offset(0, 13) = dict(CStr(.Range("G" & i)))
            End If
        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

The code below is based on your comments and the structure of the data you've attached. It assumes that, like the dataset provided, `servername` will be separated from random text by a space. I tested this with an expansion of the dataset provided (expanded to 66K server names in `Server List` and 130K Lines in `Resolved Met`) and achieved correct results in 372.672 seconds. A bit lengthy, but it's about a 98.3% decrease in run-time when compared against the ~6 hours noted in your previous method.

```
Sub ServerNameLookup()
    Dim dict As Object

    Dim i As Long
    Dim endrow As Long

    Dim textArr
    Dim iText As Long

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Sheets("Server List")
        endrow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To endrow
            If .Range("A" & i) <> "" Then
                dict.Add CStr(.Range("A" & i)), .Range("A" & i)
            End If
        Next

    End With

    With Sheets("Resolved Met")
        endrow = .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To endrow
            textArr = Split(.Range("G" & i), " ")
            For iText = LBound(textArr) To UBound(textArr)
                If dict.Exists(CStr(textArr(iText))) Then
                    .Range("G" & i).Offset(0, 13) = dict(CStr(textArr(iText)))
                End If
            Next iText
        Next

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tale! 
I tried your code, it was really fast, however it does note brought me any results.
See that I have a list with server names and column G has has a text that has the server name, for example :
 "Unable to launch ...on **server name**"
See that the server name is among some text, that is why i use the "find" function. I am not familiar with dictionary , but i believe it looks for the exactly same value on G columns, and that is why it did not brought any results.
Any other suggestion?

Comment: You are correct in that the `Key` must be referenced exactly for this to work. Is the phrasing of the text in Column G consistent such that you could use `CStr(Replace(.Range("G" & i),"Unable to launch ...on ", ""))` to return the server name in question by replacing the preceding text with a blank value?

Comment: I have done an example. Please see google drive link bellow

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fwTMra9DsqHm0jgXa34j2U3201Zfi5lT

Comment: I've added to my answer to accommodate a solution based on the data provided.